# Как в recyclerview положить view? Как сделать границы прозрачными?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как в `RecyclerView` положить `View`? Мне нужно, чтобы в начале списка была картинка и текст, которые скрываются при скролинге, как будто это часть `RecyclerView`. К сожалению, не нашёл рабочий вариант.
И ещё, как можно сделать так, чтобы элементы в `RecyclerView` не перекрывались границами? Нужно сделать так: если элемент перемещается за пределы (границы) `RecyclerView`, то он все равно будет отображаться на экране, а не часть его, как реализовано стандартно. Иными словами, сделать границы (и область заграницами) прозрачными.

**UPDATE:**

1. Мне нужно сделать из `RecyclerView` обычный контейнер. Точнее, я хочу вставить сторонний `View` элемент, например, `ImageView`. При скролинге этот элемент скрывается, как будто этот элемент является элементом `RecyclerView`. Схема:
   [image: до скролинга]
   [image: после скролинга]
2. Я делаю Drag and Drop с `RecyclerView` в виде сетки и хочу, чтобы при долгом нажатии появлялась картинка, куда бы я перетащил выделенный элемент и удалил его. Возникла проблема в прорисовке элементов за пределами `RecyclerView` - элементы не прорисовываются. То есть нужно сделать, чтобы элементы порорисовывались поверх других `View`, вот так:

[image: до долгого тапа]
[image: после долгого тапа]

Comment: Ваш вопрос нужно разделить, и конкретизировать, вопросы простые, но сейчас их штук 5 в одном. Желательно бы увидеть, что вы делаете, так вы точней и быстрей получите ответ, который сможете использовать.

Comment: Окей. Мне нужно, чтобы элементы списка не перекрывались границами. То есть нужно сделать так, чтобы элементы отрисовывались за пределами границ. Стандартно они не отрисовываются.

Comment: А покажите разметку, я думаю, что необходимо правильно расставить отступы и размеры, обычно этого больше чем достаточно. Без пример сложно будет угадывать

Comment: еще очень шорошо было бы, если бы вы схематически нарисовали то, чего вы добиваетесь. Все-таки сложно понять, как именно должны рисоваться элементы.

Comment: Андрей, полагаю, разметка Вам вряд ли поможет. Я добавил схемы и описание задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, отвечаю на свой второй вопрос. Ответ пришел откуда не ждал, а должен был.
Чтобы элементы RecyclerView прорисовывались поверх остальных, нужно указать `android:clipToPadding="false"`
 в разметке или `recyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);` в коде.